# R - Subsetting dataframe in for loop with double and single brackets

Tags: r, for-loop, square-bracket

I'm trying to create a for loop that appends a string to each data point in a data frame. I'm using a for loop since the data frame may vary with the number of columns. This is an example of the a possible data frame.

```
lexicon <- data.frame(
    X.lx = c("word", "word2", "word3"),
    X.ph = c("phonetic", "", "phonetic2")
)
```

I managed to create a loop that takes the name of the column and appends it to the data points (the data are stored in a data frame `lexicon`:

```
for(i in names(lexicon)){
   lexicon[[i]] <- sub("^", paste(names(lexicon[i]), " ", sep=""), lexicon[[i]])
}
```

This produces:

```
  X.lx        X.ph
1 X.lx word   X.ph phonetic
2 X.lx word2  X.ph 
3 X.lx word3  X.ph phonetic2
```

I'm trying to set the loop such as empty data point in the data frame are skipped by `sub()`, without success. The desired output would be

```
  X.lx        X.ph
1 X.lx word   X.ph phonetic
2 X.lx word2   
3 X.lx word3  X.ph phonetic2
```

This is my trial code:

```
for(i in names(lexicon)){
   lexicon[[i]][which(lexicon[[i]] != "")] <- sub("^", paste(names(lexicon[i]), " ", sep=""), lexicon[[i]][which(lexicon[[i]] != "")])
}
```

I receive this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, which(lexicon[[i]] != ""), value = c(NA_integer_,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How can I correctly achieve empty cells to be skipped?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example please?

Comment: Any specific reason you using a `for` loop here? Please provide `dput(lexicon))` and your desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lexicon[] <- mapply(function(x, n) {
  ifelse(x == "", "", paste(n, x))
}, lexicon, names(lexicon))
lexicon
#         X.lx           X.ph
# 1  X.lx word  X.ph phonetic
# 2 X.lx word2               
# 3 X.lx word3 X.ph phonetic2
```

Comment: (+1) Was just going to post this. Hope you don't mind I modified it so it will match the desired output

Comment: I had to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and it worked.